# Unable to access Parse query list items

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an app using Unity and Parse. The app takes a photo, uploads to Parse, and then a second functionality should retrieve all uploaded photos and display relevant data.

My problem is this:

I'm running a Parse Query to get all currently uploaded items from Parse and add them to a list by `objectId`. I am able to see in Unity's Inspector that the `objectId`s are being added to the list, but as soon as the query ends, the list items are returning null.

Ideally, my intent is to create a new Unity UI object for each item in the list and populate the text fields within each item with the data retrieved from Parse.

Here is the code I am working with so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Parse;

public class RetrieveAllObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform InfoCell;
    public float Vec3x;
    public float Vec3y;
    public List<string>AllObjectIds = new List<string> ();
    string objectId;
    DateTime? createdAt;
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Snapshot")
            .OrderByDescending("createdAt");

        query.FindAsync ().ContinueWith (u =>
        {
            results = u.Result;
            foreach (var result in results) {
                objectId = result.ObjectId;
                createdAt = result.CreatedAt;

                print ("Object ID: " + objectId + "\n" + "Date Created: " + createdAt);

                AllObjectIds.Add (objectId);
            }
            return AllObjectIds;
        });

        foreach (string id in AllObjectIds) {
            CreateInfoCell ();
        }
    }

    void CreateInfoCell ()
    {
            RectTransform newCell = Instantiate (InfoCell);
            newCell.transform.SetParent (this.gameObject.transform);
            newCell.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
            Vec3y = Vec3y - 50;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your post to move the Unity5 reference to tags, added the c# tag, and moved your code out of the snippet player since it's not web code.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using an IEnumerator.

Code below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Parse;

public class RetrieveAllObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform InfoCell;
    public Text IdText;
    public Text DateText;
    public float Vec3x;
    public float Vec3y;
    public List<string>AllObjectIds = new List<string> ();
    public List<string>CreatedAtDates = new List<string> ();
    public GameObject AnchorPos;
    int num;
    string objectId;
    DateTime? createdAt;
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Snapshot")
            .OrderByDescending("createdAt");

        query.FindAsync ().ContinueWith (u =>
        {
            results = u.Result;
            foreach (var result in results) {
                objectId = result.ObjectId;
                createdAt = result.CreatedAt;

                // print ("Object ID: " + objectId + "\n" + "Date Created: " + createdAt);

                AllObjectIds.Add (objectId);
                CreatedAtDates.Add (createdAt.ToString());
            }

            foreach (string id in AllObjectIds) {
                // CreateInfoCell ();
                // print (id);
            }
            foreach (string date in CreatedAtDates) {
                // CreateInfoCell ();
                // print (date);
            }
            return AllObjectIds;
            return CreatedAtDates;
        });

        StartCoroutine (UpdateUI ());
    }

    IEnumerator UpdateUI () {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Snapshot");
        Task task = query.FindAsync ();
        while(!task.IsCompleted) yield return null;
        // Do all your continue with stuff here
        foreach (string id in AllObjectIds) {
            CreateInfoCell (id);
        }
        AnchorPos.SetActive (false);
    }

    void CreateInfoCell (string id)
    {
            // print ("CELL CREATED\n");
            RectTransform newCell = Instantiate (InfoCell);
            newCell.name = id + " - " + CreatedAtDates[num];
            GameObject PutIdText = GameObject.Find(newCell.name + "/ObjectIdText");
            PutIdText.GetComponent<Text> ().text = id;
            GameObject PutDateText = GameObject.Find(newCell.name + "/DateCreatedText");
            PutDateText.GetComponent<Text> ().text = CreatedAtDates[num];

        StartCoroutine (DisplayThumbnail(newCell, id));

            // IdText.text = id;
            // DateText.text = CreatedAtDates[num];
            num++;
            newCell.transform.SetParent (this.gameObject.transform);
            newCell.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
        newCell.transform.position = new Vector3 (AnchorPos.transform.position.x, AnchorPos.transform.position.y - Vec3y, AnchorPos.transform.position.z);
            Vec3y = Vec3y + 100;
    }
```